# Node-cron on windows server

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduler, node-cron

I have used [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to schedule job in my node application and I work on ubuntu OS. Below is the code for same. I am running the scheduler every one hour and it works fine on my local machine.

```
new CronJob('0 0 * * * *', function() {
    eventController.init()
}, null, true, 'Asia/Kolkata')
```

When I deploy this code to a windows server (using [iis-node](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)) the scheduler runs every one minute. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your cron on following pattern:

```
* * */1 * * *
```

**Description:**
From left:

```
Seconds: 0-59
Minutes: 0-59
Hours: 0-23
Day of Month: 1-31
Months: 0-11
Day of Week: 0-6
```